# Using GoogleAGI inside Asterisk-java AGi

Tags: asterisk

I am using [Asterisk-java AGi](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/apidocs/index.html) and I want to use [googleTTS agi](http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-googletts/) in my server.
Can I use google tts agi inside my agi?Is there any command for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use AGI inside another AGI !

AGI use STDIN/STDOUT to read/write information from Asterisk ...

Comment: any reason why you think so? there are alot of posible ways to use one agi inside enother.

Comment: I agree with arheops. It's possible, but trying to integrate calling a perl app, and passing STDIN/OUT from this guy's java app is kind of a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to take 4 years to give you an answer, but you can do this using the command "channel.exec()".

Probably you could solve this by yourself. Posting this answer just for documentation purposes.

```
    public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel)
        throws AgiException
{
    // Answer the channel...
    answer();

    // ...say hello...
    channel.exec("AGI","googletts.agi","Olá Mundo!","pt-BR");

    // ...and hangup.
    hangup();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you really want to do is call the two AGI's sequentially (in your dialplan) and pass the information to your AGI script.

So, in your AGI script (the one using Asterisk-Java) set a variable to the value you want for TTS, then... Finish execution of your AGI script and pass it back to the dialplan, and use that variable for google TTS.

```
exten => your_exten,1,Noop(Begin here)
same => n, Answer()
same => n, AGI(/path/to/your/AGI.script) ; or fastAGI etc.
same => n, Noop(This is the variable I set in my agi script: ${TEXT_TO_SPEAK})
same => n, AGI(googletts.agi,${TEXT_TO_SPEAK},en)
same => n, Hangup()
```

**Don't** get caught in the trap of trying to control everything in Asterisk through your AGI script. You're wasting your time, and using Asterisk inefficiently if you do that. Call your AGI applications when you need to do something that Asterisk cannot do.